# Android SyncAdapter behaving weirdly

Tags: android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I've created a Sync Adapter without Content Provider and Account Type, but it started behaving weirdly in my Nexus 5 by restarting and optimising for apps as mentioned in the below forum:

http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-6/502930-phone-keeps-rebooting-optimizing-apps-what-did-i-do-lol.html

Can anyone explain why this behavior? Is it that it tries to sync everything in the device as I had given the Content Provider and AccountType as empty?

Configuration of the service and Sync adapter is given below.

```
    <service
        android:name=".service.SessionSyncService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>

    <sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        Android: contentAuthority=""
        android:accountType=""
        android:userVisible="false"
        android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
        android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
        android:supportsUploading="false"/>
```